# Function to test the type of the entered value

Tags: c, file, loops, int, fwrite

I want to create a loop that will keep reading values (Integers in here) until a non-integer is entered.
 For example, here is the code I've written

```
while(true)
 {
    scanf("%d",&w);
    if (w==100) break;
    else fwrite(&w,sizeof(int),1,f);
 }
```

---

Only right there the test is for the user to type in the number 100. But what I'm of searching for is a function or some kinda way that will test whether it's an integer or not or one that will detect an error with the entered value. `isdigit()` doesn't seem to pull the trick over here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the return value form `scanf`

```
if (scanf("%d", &w)) != 1) {
    /* error, input doesn't match. */
}
```

Alternatively you can ditch `scanf` and just read a string with `fgets`. Then you can walk the string and do `isdigit` and decide if you like the input or not.